# Regarding insertion of nodes at the beginning of a linked list (Program isn't executing properly)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
   int data;
   node* link;
};

node* a;//global variable declared for creating head, not local as in 1.cpp

void Insert(int x);
void Print();

int main()
{
   int i,n,x;

   a=NULL;

   cout<<"How many numbers do you want to enter?";
   cin>>n;

   for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      cout<<"Enter your desired numbers\n:";
      cin>>x;
      Insert(x);
      Print();
   }

   return 0;
}

void Insert(int x)//first node from file 1
{
   node* temp=new node();
   temp->data=x;
   temp->link=NULL;
   a=temp; 
}

void Print()//check this part out again.
{
   node* temp=a;
   cout<<"The list is";
   while (temp!=NULL) {
      cout<<temp->data;
      temp=temp->link;

   }

   printf("\n");   
}
```

I think something is wrong in the Print function I created. 
I tried to debug it a couple times but couldn't arrive at a solution
Can you tell me whats wrong with it? I want to use this same method, using functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating the links properly.

```
void Insert(int x)
{
   node* temp=new node();
   temp->data=x;

   // This makes temp a standalone node.    
   // temp->link=NULL;

   // Make the link between the new node and the
   // existing nodes.
   temp->link= a;

   a=temp; 
}
```